# AWS S3 bucket to bucket sync using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-s3

I have to create a Nodejs script to perform the **S3 bucket to bucket sync**. I don't want to run this when a file is just uploaded to the master S3, so I think lambda is not an option. I need to run the task daily once at a particular time.

How can I achieve this S3 bucket sync using **NodeJS** using **aws-sdk**?

Cron can be used for scheduling. I found only aws-sdk code to copy from S3 to another S3. Do we have a code in place to sync two S3 buckets?

Comment: Looks like you want to implement a cron job. There is a package for node to implement this (node-cron)

Comment: refer [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

Comment: Cron can be used for scheduling. I found only aws-sdk code to copy from S3 to another S3. Do we have a code in place to sync two S3 buckets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS S3 Bucket synchronization using Nodejs and `aws-sdk` can be performed by the method of the [s3sync package](https://github.com/issacg/s3sync). If you use it with `node-cron`, you will be able to implement AWS S3 bucket synchronization scheduling through Nodejs.

---

I don't know if it'll help, if Cron and [aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html) are available, the purpose can be achieved without Nodejs.
You simply add the code below to the `crontab`.

`0 0 * * * aws s3 sync s3://bucket-name-1 s3://bucket-name-2`

Comment: The package mentioned in this answer has not been maintained for 7 years. I wonder if there is the more updated and active package?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a cron job and nodejs provides a library named **[node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)**

```
let cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  // TODO
  ...
});
```

For daily cron you can use something like

```
0 0 * * *
```

The first 0 specifies the minutes and the second the hours so this cron will run every day at midnight.